# Hook into gdb or make gdb execute command on exception

Tags: gdb

Sometimes I am trying to debug a program in `gdb` and it takes it a while of running before the bug comes up.

While I'm waiting, I like to do other things. It would be nice if gdb could beep at me when an exception happens.

Is there a way to make gdb run an external command when an exception happens? Or a standard way to hook into gdb for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `define` and `shell`, so:

```
(gdb) define nrun
run
shell notify-send "Go look at GDB now...."
end
```

This creates a new command `nrun` (for notify run) that does a `run` command, then when the `run` has finished uses `shell` to execute `notify-send`.

The `notify-send` is nothing to do with `gdb`, this is just a program in my `$PATH` that causes a popup notification dialogue to appear, you could replace `notify-send` with anything that you want.

Now instead of using `run` I use `nrun`, and once `gdb` stops I see a notification to go look at gdb.

You can add the `define` for `nrun` to your `~/.gdbinit` file, and then it will always be available, if you're going to do that you might also want to add some documentation, like this:

```
documentation nrun
Perform a standard run command and notify the user when gdb stops.
end
```

Now in `gdb` if your forget what your command does you can do this:

```
(gdb) help nrun
Perform a standard run command and notify the user when gdb stops.
```

And if you forget what you called you command, but you know that it performs a notify when gdb stops you can do this:

```
(gdb) apropos notify
nrun -- Perform a standard run command and notify the user when gdb stops.
```